# 3rd order differential equations examples

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

one example of 2nd order diff equation that I can think of is spring mass damper system.

$ x''+c/mx'+k/mx = f $

What are examples of 3rd order differential equations?

Comment: Improbable to find one in mechanics, where Newton equation is a second order ODE

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/post/Are_there_examples_of_third-order_linear_differential_equations_in_physics_or_applied_mathematics

Comment: Look the book Theory of Third-Order Differential Equations - Seshadev Padhi and Smita Pati

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266003546_Some_third-order_differential_equations_in_physics

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there examples of third-(or higher)-order linear differential equations in physics or applied mathematics?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2167292/are-there-examples-of-third-or-higher-order-linear-differential-equations-in-p)